# Iterating the dimensional kernel of a metric space

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, dimension-theory

Fix $n\in \mathbb N$. Let $X$ be a separable metric space of (inductive) dimension $n$.  Let
\begin{align}
\Lambda(X)&=\{x\in X:X\text{ is $n$-dimensional at }x\}\\ \\
\Lambda^2(X)&=\Lambda(\Lambda(X))\\
&(=\{x\in \Lambda(X):\Lambda(X)\text{ is $n$-dimensional at }x\})\\ \\
\Lambda^3(X)&=\Lambda(\Lambda^2(X))
\end{align}

> Note that there are *weakly $n$-dimensional* spaces which have the
> property $\dim(X)=n$ and  $\dim(\Lambda(X))<n$. In this case,
> $\Lambda(X)\neq\varnothing$ while $\Lambda^2(X)=\varnothing$. In
> particular, $\Lambda^2(X)\neq \Lambda(X)$.

**Question.** Is $\Lambda^3(X)=\Lambda^2(X)$?

I am primarily interested in this question when $n=1$.

Comment: Isn't $\Lambda^2(X)$ computed relative to the dimension of $\Lambda(X)$? In that case $\Lambda^2(X)$ need not be empty if $\dim\Lambda(X)<\dim X$.

Comment: @KPHart I see your point. I suppose I want to fix $n$ at the outset, so that $\Lambda^2(X)$ is the set of points at which $\Lambda(X)$ is $n$-dimensional, etc. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer in general is "no". The Cook-Lelek continuum $X$ described in Figure 1 of the paper below has a left-most segment (arc) $S$ which can be replaced with a copy of $X$. Since the continuum $X$ is chainable, it should be possible to do this in a natural way. Call the new continuum $Y$. There is a countable set $Q$ intersecting each arc in $Y$, and the counterexample is the space $Y\setminus Q$. For this space it can be proved that $\Lambda^2$ is non-empty whereas $\Lambda^3$ is empty.

*Lipham, David S.*, [**Totally disconnected subsets of chainable continua**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2022.108187), Topology Appl. 317, Article ID 108187, 4 p. (2022). [ZBL1495.54019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1495.54019).